# How can non-coders use programs on Github?

Tags: git

Excuse my ignorance but I know nothing about coding. However, there have been many times when I have seen very interesting programs on GitHub. The problem is I have no idea how to use them. Without a setup file, I don't know what I am doing.

For example, I want to use the program developed here: https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus. But when I download the files, I don't understand how to install this or get it functioning on my computer.

Please give very basic steps on how to use programs like this.

Comment: You don't have to be *"coder"* to use source code.  One purpose for providing the source code is to allow the program to be built (or even ported) to other systems or platforms that don't already offer pre-built, ready-to-run executables.  Typically you would need to install a toolchain to build the program from source code.

Comment: What kind of toolchain? Are there generic ones that can build a range of programs from source code?

Comment: A toolchain is typically language, operating system and architecture specific for both the host and target systems.  I have only been using C toolchains (both native and cross), and know nothing about Java and Python build environments.  For the site you specifically mentioned,  the README file has a how-to `Building` section.

Comment: Code on Github is really just source code or scripts. There is no one way to run anything on GitHub; each repo has it’s own needs. In your case the instructions are [here in the README file in the repo](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus#building). Or just download a [release](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus/releases), unZip it and then just run it like any application.

Comment: What OS are you on? Your question reads as very general but it’s actually very specific: If you are on macOS, just go to the “[releases](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus/releases)”  link on the repo, download a recompiled release, unZip it and enjoy the program without compiling from source. Voting to close because a general question about using GitHub code—which is a massive repository—is fairly unanswerable.

Comment: This would wildly vary by the target OS and the programming language(s) used.

Comment: @sawdust Eh, I'm not sure I agree. How easy it is to build a project varies wildly, but for most projects, understanding the norms of how stuff written for the target language or platform typically gets built or run is going to be at least helpful, and for some it's outright *necessary*. Unfortunately, that is knowledge that typically only coders who have used that language or platform are going to have. I've been a professional dev for years and sometimes still take a miserable day of trial-and-error and Googling to get a poorly-documented tool written in a language I don't know to work.

Comment: @kandyman to be honest, getting started is not hard at all! Languages like [Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVp1vrfL_w4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M) were actually ***designed*** to be *"learning"* / *"educational"* languages.

Comment: @sawdust I just asked my mum (who isn't a "_coder_" but can use a PC fine enough) to follow your comment. She has the following questions: "What's a toolchain? "Is English ok for the language?" "What's an operating system?" "What's an architecture?" "What's a host?" "What's a target system?" "What's a C toolchain?" "What's native?" "What's cross?" "What's Java?" "What's Python?" "What's a build environment?"

Comment: @kandyman The project you have linked has published releaes. These are already compiled versions of the software that anyone can download and run. If there isn't an installer then you can typically move the software to any folder you like and just run it. (If it needs some special setup; there should be a readme file telling you what to do) You can find the releases for the linked project here: https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus/releases

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If you want actual instructions on installing this particular project, skip to the bottom of this answer. Everything beforehand applies more generally to any kind of project on GitHub.

**A Quick Note On GitHub Releases**

Sometimes the author(s) of a program will have pre-built releases on GitHub. Assuming these files exist, they can typically be accessed by appending "releases" to the project URL e.g. `https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus/releases`. They can also be accessed from the main project page via any "Releases" links (located in the lower right-hand portion of the page, next to the main file list):

*ex. GitHub Releases Links*

[image: GitHub Releases Link Example - Screenshot. A cropped image of the main GitHub web interface is marked in a red square. A text link inside the marked area reads Releases, 90, which leads to a list of all the GitHub Releases for the project. A separate text link below Releases, 90, links to the most recent release, with the identifier 7 dot 11 dot 1 and a GitHub generated tag reading Latest. Additionally, a text tag below that link reads, 3 days ago. This latest release link leads to a page just for that GitHub release, with no other releases listed. A third and final text link below the latest release link reads + 89 releases, and leads to the same page as Releases, 90]

**Operating System Support**

Not all projects are supported on all operating systems. Determining what platforms a project supports is part of the research mentioned below, even though it isn't explicitly stated. For what it is worth, projects in interpreted languages tend to be cross-platform while projects in compiled languages tend not to be (but this isn't an absolute given).

---

**Overview**

> There have been many times when I have seen very interesting programs on Github. The problem is I have no idea how to use them.

As alluded to in the other answers to this question, the basic process is to do a small amount of research and see if there is any documentation for the project. This can give you the following insights:

- *Is it a program or a library?*

In short, libraries are collections of functions or data that typically cannot be used outside of other programs (they are not stand alone). Some libraries may come with tools to use them in a standalone manner or with other support tools to use outside the library itself, but this isn't common.

- *What language is it written in?*

Determining the programming language the software is written in can help determine what additional programs may be needed to support the project.

- *Is the program in a language that is [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) or is it [scripted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)?*

The practical impact of this is that scripted languages essentially always need at least one additional program (their *interpreter*) to run. Compiled languages may need special tools (a *toolchain*) to turn them into executable programs or (ideally) may have already been made or compiled. This may be done by the author(s) on GitHub, but this may also be done by someone else.

Lists of [compiled languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language#Languages) as well as [scripted languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scripting_languages) are available from Wikipedia.

- *Are there demonstrations regarding how to use the software?*

Whoever is creating the software will often provide a list of requirements for the project (i.e. any necessary support software) and/or demonstrations on how to use that software. This isn't universal, but again, this is typically found in the documentation (if any) for the project.

- *Are there links to any external websites?*

For a variety of reasons, not all the documentation or software needed for a program or project may be kept on GitHub. In this case, using Google to research the software or noting external links created by the author(s) can be extremely helpful as they may contain clues (or actual instructions) on how to use that software.

It is probably worth mentioning that there is no generic solution for determining exactly what a project needs in order to be run successfully. As already noted, there will always be some amount of research required. But as you gain familiarity with the projects hosted on GitHub overall, patterns will emerge that will make using them eventually easier.

---

**A Practical Example**

> For example, I want to use the program developed here: https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus. But when I download the files, I don't understand how to install this or get it functioning on my computer.

1. *Is it a program or a library?*

From the GitHub page you linked to, the phrase "wrapped into one single app" in the project description and the accompanying screenshots seem to clearly indicate it has some kind of stand-alone functionality (so it is probably not a traditional library).

2. *What language is it in?*

Again, from the project description, it clearly states "built with Electron". If we click the link provided (marked "Electron"), we are taken to the [Electron Framework homepage](https://electronjs.org/), which uses JavaScript, HTML, and CSS (as stated in its own description).

So it would seem likely our application was built on "JavaScript, HTML, and CSS". This seems to be confirmed by the `.js` and `.json` file extensions clearly visible in the primary file listings:

*ex. Main File Listing*

[image: JavaScript File Extensions Example - Screenshot. A cropped image of the main GitHub web interface shows a list of source code files and folders. Several individual files in the main list are marked with red squares. These files, in order, are titled main dot J S, package hyphen lock dot jay sun, J S O N, package dot jay sun, J S O N, and settings dot jay sun, J S O N]

Note that this is just an example of what to look for overall. GitHub provides a breakdown of the language(s) used in the project (by percentage) below any "Releases" links (again, located in the lower right-hand portion of the page, next to the main file list):

*ex. GitHub Language Breakdown*

[image: GitHub Language Breakdown Bar Example - Screenshot. A cropped image of the main GitHub web interface shows a colorful bar consisting of yellow, orange and purple in different proportions. Below the bar are GitHub generated text tags showing language use, by percentage, for the project. They are titled JavaScript, 80 dot 3 percent, marked with a yellow dot, H T M L, 18 dot 2 percent, marked with an orange dot, and C S S, 1 dot 5 percent, marked with a purple dot, respectively]

---

*Be aware that this language breakdown may not always be immediately visible. Recently, GitHub has chosen to place this breakdown at the relative bottom of its web interface. On the mobile version of the site, at least in some cases, it is literally the last item listed when scrolling down.*

---

3. Is JavaScript a compiled or scripted language?

JavaScript is a [scripted language per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scripting_languages). Therefore, since the software is written in JavaScript, it needs an additional program to run (an *interpreter*, as previously stated).

So how do you run JavaScript on your PC? This might actually be the hardest part to determine but we have some clues. If we scroll all the way down and read the [Building section](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus#building) on the main GitHub project page:

> You'll need Node.js installed on your computer in order to build this app.

Clicking the link marked "Node.js" takes us to the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) website, which has [nice, friendly, not-at-all scary installers](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

4. *Are there demonstrations regarding how to use the software?*

If we read the next part of the [Building section](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus#building), we find these instructions:

```
 git clone https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus
 cd unicopedia-plus
 npm install
 npm start
```

---

**Text Instructions**

As a small note, whenever you see text instructions, this typically means you need to use a terminal or command window and type the instructions given. On Windows you can use `cmd.exe` (Start Menu → Search → *cmd* → <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Any Mac or Linux distribution should have prominent links to relevant terminal applications.

*ex. Windows Command Window (cmd.exe)*

[image: Windows Command Window CMD - Screenshot. A cropped image of the Windows Command console shows a line with the text git, clone, https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus]

Also, before following any instructions, you will want to install all the prerequisite software. In this instance, this means [installing Node.js first](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). The option to add `node` and `npm` to your path (important for Steps 3 and 4) should already be selected when using the Windows installer.

---

*If you get an error about `npm` not being recognized in Windows (Step 3 below):*

- *Close the current command window, open a new one and try again.*
- *You may need to log out and log in again to reload your environment variables.*
- *You may still need to [add npm to your Windows Path manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10), assuming something was mismarked during your Node.js installation.*

*Any solutions for similar issues on Mac/Linux should be readily available online.*

---

**Installing Unicopedia Plus**

Following the steps given on the GitHub project page:

1. We can ignore `git clone https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus` which simply tells us to download the files using [git](https://git-scm.com/), the program GitHub is named after. We, as normal non-programmers, will simply click the big green "Code" button and select "Download ZIP":

*ex. GitHub Code Button*

[image: GitHub Code Button - Screenshot. A cropped image of the main GitHub web interface shows a button link titled Code in green. Below that, an H T M L generated submenu offers three option links. These are titled Clone with H T T P S, Open with GitHub Desktop, and Download Zip, respectively. The final link, Download Zip, is marked with a red square]

2. After we extract our `.zip` file with a program such as [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), we are ready for our next instruction `cd unicopedia-plus`. In this case, `cd` is a command to switch folders ("change directory") and it tells us we need to navigate to the extracted `unicopedia-plus` folder (this should contain `main.js`).

---

*It is important to note here that the portion after `cd` may not be "just" `unicopedia-plus`.*

*The second portion may be different depending on:*

- *Where the command window or terminal is launched from.*
- *Where you have chosen to store or extract your `.zip` file.*
- *What the file or folder you downloaded is actually called (e.g. "unicopedia-plus-master" for the `.zip` version).*

*The solution to this is to determine the full path to the "proper" local `unicopedia-plus` directory and use that instead e.g. `cd C:\some\path\to\unicopedia-plus-folder` for Windows or `cd /some/path/to/unicopedia-plus-folder` for Mac and Linux.*

---

3. The next instruction we encounter is `npm install`. To skip any trouble, we have already installed Node.js with `npm` added to our path (above) and navigated to the proper `unicopedia-plus` folder (the one containing `main.js`) in our command window or terminal (the previous step).

So we simply need to type `npm install` and let the setup/build process do its thing (like a normal installer).

Note that there may be some additional requirements that are downloaded and installed automatically during this process, so make sure to have a working internet connection. You will be returned to the command line when installation is finished. Be patient. =)

---

*We have also (hypothetically) done some research and found that `npm` is the "node package manager", a command-line utility included with Node.js. `npm` is used for "interacting" with various Node.js projects such as ours, which includes installation, management and an interface to work with anything we have installed.*

---

4. Start the program with the final command `npm start`. You should get the graphical user interface shown on the GitHub page. This seemed to take around 30 seconds or so during testing, so again, be patient. =)

---

*On Windows, you can create a batch file to start this project like so:*

*1. Create a new text file.*

*2. Type something similar to the following:*

```
    cd "C:\path\to\unicopedia-plus-folder"
    npm start
```

*3. Save this file and change the file extension from `.txt` to `.bat`.*

*4. Double-click the `.bat` (batch) file when you wish to start the graphical user interface for the project.*

*You can substitute `C:\path\to\nodejs\npm.cmd start` in place of `npm start` if you run into issues.*

---

Comment: Or if you are on macOS, just go to the “[releases](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus/releases)”  link on the repo, download a recompiled release, unZip it and enjoy the program without compiling from source.

Comment: This is way too complicated for someone who says "without a setup file, I'm lost". But that's just the way it is, so have an upvote. I've been a coder for 30+ years, and sometimes I still need several hours (or even give up) on projects that use an unfamiliar (to me) toolchain or have a lot of dependencies. In some cases I have to tweak a bit of the code to get it to compile/run on my system. As a standard user, checking the "Releases" tab, or trying to find a website that provides a compiled version (with all caveats ...) is more or less your only option.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I had no idea it could be this complicated, but I really appreciate the time you took to put this answer together. I will read through it carefully and do my best to follow the instructions you have provided. Much appreciated.

Comment: @kandyman Your welcome. =) I would say the important thing is not to be too daunted. I didn't mention it in my answer but sites like [readthedocs.io](https://readthedocs.org/) (which hosts open source project documentation), as well any personal sites hosted by the author(s) can be a life saver. There are also plenty of useful patterns. For instance, `npm` has rough equivalents in other interpreted languages such as Python (`pip`) and Ruby (`gem`). Compiled languages may have Integrated Development Environments available and files that can help you build projects.

Comment: Also note that for the `What language is it in?` part, you can click on the colored bar and get details (e.g. Unicodepedia: 80.1% JavaScript, 17.9% HTML, 2.0% CSS)

Comment: "Use the release if it exists" seems like the first thing one should try, but somehow you managed to describe it using manual URL manipulation?! On the projects main page there is a link to releases if they exist.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I managed to get the program built and working using your instructions. Thanks again for your great post ! I also got the batch file working too!

Comment: @kandyman No problem. =P Great to hear that everything went well. That's awesome. =)

Answer (score 4):

The app on your example runs on electron so you should Google how to run such an app and you should find the official documentation.

For your example, I have done it for you and found the documentation, go to: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#trying-this-example

Also you will find that the readme file is quite helpful too in some cases.

I have not given I step by step instruction to your example but a more general answer so as to enable you do such things your self in the future.

Comment: Electron is installed and built automatically via the build instructions, meaning it be ignored if we are only interested in using this github project.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a **Building** or **Installing** section of the github project.

In this case, they are:

#### Build Instructions for unicopedia-plus

*You'll need Node.js installed on your computer in order to build this app.*

```
git clone https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus
cd unicopedia-plus
npm install
npm start
```

#### How to follow the above instructions

1. Install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads), a core tool if working with github
2. Go to nodejs.org, download and install node.js
3. Execute the above commands in terminal (or command prompt). Copy and pasting them all at once should work fine
4. Follow the instructions printed in terminal if any exist

Most projects will fundamentally follow the above three steps for build/installation.

If there are not easy to decipher *Build* or *Installation* instructions to be found on the github project, it's likely that the software isn't yet ready for anything more than developer use.

Comment: The instructions fail to address that you'll also need git installed to execute the first command.

Comment: Sorry @Džuris you're right I overlooked that. Updated now.